# Odd behavior on orientation change with a listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Not sure why this is happening, but (sometimes) when I change the orientation of a device, this is the output I get:

[image]

Only appears to be happening on iPad. Not iPhone. Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up navigating back to the same page to avoid this. Seems something in my code or perhaps a limitation in Xamarin, I have a complex set up for this so that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug in the binding of a ObservableCollection to a ListView.

You could force a refresh in the ListView by overriding the `OnSizeAllocated` of the current ContentPage.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    ExampleListView.ItemsSource = null;
    ExampleListView.ItemsSource = ObservableCollection;
}
```

Comment: `OnAppearing` doesn't get called when orientation change.

Comment: I would rather just completely reload the page in it's entirety. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You are right, I wanted OnSizeAllocated. Did you try to call Invalidate() on the Content View Control? https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Layout.InvalidateLayout()/